# how to List all phpmyadmin user/pass for Linux

Tags: java, php, phpmyadmin, vps

how to List all phpmyadmin user/pass for Linux as i forgot the DB password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start mysql server without authentication

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Login to mysql server

```
mysql --user=root mysql
```

reset the password of any user inclusing root

```
update user set Password=PASSWORD('new_password') where user='user_name';
```

Now start the server and use the new password.

Comment: not an easy way .. may be some password cracker may help you .. but I have no idea as of now .. better set new password and use it ..

Comment: @gourav, modern MySQL passwords are hashed well enough that they can not be cracked in a sane amount of time.  Your valuable time is going to be better-spent simply regaining control of the root account and *resetting* the passwords you need to a known value.